# How to pass objects between qml

Tags: qt, object, model, qml, listmodel

I want to pass an objects from one qml to other qml.
I have a list model.

```
ListModel {
       id:favouriteapp
           ListElement {
               id: 1
               name:"ABSC"
               title:"5:03pm"
               description:"heloo-1"
               icon1:"images/climate_icon.png"
               icon2:"images/climate_icon.png"
               pinStatus : false
               isLoaded: false

           }
           ListElement {
               id: 2
               name:"GHTT"
               title:"Home at 5:23pm"
               description:"via Gaydon Road-2"
               icon1:"images/navigation_icon.png"
               icon2:"images/navigation_icon.png"
               pinStatus : false
               isLoaded: false

           }
}
```

Now I want to pass each property of the `ListElement` via string value to other qml.

How can I pass this entire `ListElement` object to other qml.

Comment: first of all `id` should not be a string nor a number. [Read](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#the-id-attribute) the docs. Just make it, for example `id: obj1` and so pass `obj1` as a reference to the item.

Comment: @folibis: id is one of the property in my 'ListElement ' I have edited the code

Comment: You just removed `id`s? Did you read my answer?

Comment: @folibis: instead of string how can I pass the id of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @folibis said, you need to give a correct id to your object

```
ListElement {
    id: obj1
    ...
}
```

Here is `MyFile.qml` to which you can pass the reference to your `ListElement` object:

```
Item{
    ...
    function myFunction(listElementObject){
        //whatever you need to do with your object
    }
}
```

And in the same QML file as the `ListModel` you'll have

```
MyFile{
    id: myFileId
}

Component.onCompleted: myFileId.myFunction(obj1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `favouriteapp.get()` to access any of the list elements as a JavaScript object and pass this object on to where ever you need it.

You could also allow the other component access to the model and let it access the list element it needs.

You could also have the other component provide a data object or separate properties and bind those in the place where you have access to the model.

Comment: by using the 'favouriteapp.get()' how can I access the model from other qml.  My Model Id 'favouriteapp' scope is in first qml only.

Comment: You mean option 2? Add a property to the other component and assign your listmodel to that property

Comment: NO. I wan to pass an object from one qml to other qml.

Comment: I've listed three options. You asked how to do option 2. I've answered that as well. So how does repeating your question help here?